# downloaded videos with python requests don't work

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests, urllib

I'm trying to scrape video using requests or urllib but once its downloaded it haven't sound and its a little bit longer then the original :

```
# 1st code :
import requests
url = "https://link/to/the/video.mp4"
path = "c:/Users/MyProfile/Desktop/video1.mp4"

obj = requests.get(url)
with open(path, "wb") as out_file :
    out_file.write(obj.content)

# 2nd code :
import urllib
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, path)
```